# How can I improve color saturation in Ubuntu?

Tags: color-management

My laptop, a Thinkpad T430 with Intel HD4000 graphics, shows pretty desaturated colors by default. On Windows I can just increase saturation using the Intel Graphics and Media Control Panel to get extremely lively colors. Is there any tweak/application that I can use to get similar results in Ubuntu?

Comment: If you're experiencing problems on an external monitor over HDMI, try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/640153/109848

Answer (score 2):

this can be made with xrandr, first identify you video output running "xrandr" and look into the output sor something like this:

```
DVI-I-1 connected 1600x900+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

in my case, my output is DVI-I-1, now i run "xrandr --props" to know what properties can i change.

```
scaling mode: None 
    supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
color vibrance: 180 
    range: (0, 200)
vibrant hue: 90 
    range: (0, 180)
non-desktop: 0 
    range: (0, 1)
link-status: Good 
    supported: Good, Bad
```

to change the saturation, in my case (Old GeForce GT 520), i run the following:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --set "color vibrance" "180"
```

Hope this works for all you guys.
(same response: [how-to-adjust-screen-settings-contrast-color-saturation-etc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756082/how-to-adjust-screen-settings-contrast-color-saturation-etc))

Answer (score 1):

There is `gnome-color-manager` (Ubuntu Repository): from a console (xterm is fine) do `sudo apt-get install gnome-color-manager`. It should also run with other window managers but is a bit heavy.
Let me know if you solve, good evening.

Comment: Gnome Color Manager only allows me to install color profiles, and I don't have a calibrating device to create custom ones. Still the color profiles for the T430 that I have found on the web only give my screen a warm or cold tint, without affecting saturation.