# How to adjust screen settings: contrast, color saturation, etc

Tags: xubuntu, screen, settings

using Xubuntu 14.04 with a HP mini notebook.

I can't seem to find any program to adjust screen settings: contrast, brightness, and more importantly: color saturation, tint and gamma.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You might also be interested in this post from a while ago : [Is there any brightness control for desktops?](http://askubuntu.com/q/583863/295286)

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I use terminal commands `xgamma` for contrast and occasionally  `xrandr` for brightness (though mostly I use the native brightness setting - more on that later ).

To change contrast with `xgamma` , do

```
xgamma -gamma $1
```

Where `$1` is a decimal value. It can be 1.5 or .5 , but the values above those values can be harsh on the eyes, so play with the values in that range.

To change brightness  with `xrandr` , you need to know the name of your display. Run `xrandr` to find that out, should be mentioned as `connected primary`.

To change brightness, do

```
  xrandr --output $SCREEN --brightness $VALUE
```

where `$SCREEN`  is the value of your connected primary and `$VALUE` is decimal number, again in range from 0 (completely off) to whatever

Personally , what I'd do is spawn `gnome-settings-daemon` or `unity-settings-daemon` command , whichever is available, and use the following two commands to change brightness :

```
qdbus org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepUp
qdbus org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepDown
```

( provided of course that you have `qdbus` installed ; it is so for Default Ubuntu with Unity, but I don't know about Xubuntu .  If you don't have the settings daemon, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install gnome-settings-daemon` )

Comment: I think that just setting up Gnome in Xubuntu is complicated.

Comment: We're not setting up Gnome in Xubuntu though. All we need is the settings daemon which will help us set up sound and brightness in easy way. I've used this method for openbox environment, which is very very minimalistic and it worked perfectly

Comment: From `man xrandr`: --brightness brightness Multiply the gamma values on the crtc currently attached to the output to specified floating value. Useful for overly bright or overly dim outputs. However, this is a software only modification, if your hardware has support to actually change the brightness, you will probably prefer to use **xbacklight**.

Comment: @vstepaniuk Correct. xrandr is software method only, i.e. there's no change in power consumption by screen itself. But xbacklight has history of being inconsistent with Ubuntu, and in most cases doesn't seem to work.  I'd encourage users to try and see for themselves

Answer (score 1):

this can be made with xrandr, first identify you video output running "xrandr" and look into the output sor something like this:

```
DVI-I-1 connected 1600x900+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

in my case, my output is DVI-I-1, now i run "xrandr --props" to know what properties can i change.

```
scaling mode: None 
    supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
color vibrance: 180 
    range: (0, 200)
vibrant hue: 90 
    range: (0, 180)
non-desktop: 0 
    range: (0, 1)
link-status: Good 
    supported: Good, Bad
```

to change the saturation, in my case (Old GeForce GT 520), i run the following:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --set "color vibrance" "180"
```

Hope this works for all you guys.