# In Ubuntu 18.04 how do you adjust display saturation?

Tags: display

In Ubuntu 18.04 how do you adjust display saturation?
I'm not referring to application-level saturation that tools like Compiz provides, what I mean is system-wide saturation. In Windows OS, this can be done in Intel HD software, but in any Linux distro, including Ubuntu, it seems that this is impossible.

Is there a way to set display saturation with Ubuntu?

Comment: Like this https://askubuntu.com/questions/756082/how-to-adjust-screen-settings-contrast-color-saturation-etc/756266

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to adjust screen settings: contrast, color saturation, etc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756082/how-to-adjust-screen-settings-contrast-color-saturation-etc)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer to your question is currently at the mercy of Intel and whether or not they themselves are going to continue the graphics drivers (Including color saturation. Yes, I do know what this is you are talking about unlike many out there lol) and their adjustments on Ubuntu and such.

I hate to break it to you but as far as I've looked into this, the only things that are currently adjustable (AS OF NOW, mind you...) are the gamma, brightness and color "tint", using `xgamma`.

To put it more bluntly, the answer is that there is no answer to this right now in terms of Intel cards except for those adjustments I mentioned above.

It seems Intel has either abandoned working on it or are working on something better for future release. I have seen no announcements to anything new except on [Intel's old site](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/about) that they used to have the driver installers on when they were up and running. They said something like (not a quote) *we are going to be integrating the drivers into the actual Linux distros more in the future than having people download a separate installer*.

There are plenty of answers on how to adjust the nVidia and AMD graphics cards so searching online would help with those. There are also tutorials on how to install the "source code" drivers for advanced users if that is your skill level.

Excuse me for the blunt posting but I am currently looking for something like this myself and have found nothing. Not even an old driver that might work. I'm on 16.04 MATE, Ubuntu, and nothing here yet either in terms of a dedicated saturation adjustment. I have an ASUS laptop and turning the brightness (gamma) using `xgamma` makes it look so washed out, color wise.

I have found [a GUI for `xgamma`](https://github.com/dfc643/xgamma-gui). I've found it needs to be "reset" (the <kbd>Restore</kbd> button on the bottom right does the trick) on first running it as it seems to have been preset incorrectly. And from there it's easy to adjust and save. You just download it and open the folder, run the `XgammaGui` file (It's the purple icon with gears inside it here on MATE 16) and it sets `xgamma` for you. It's nice as it does show you the whole screen "preview" before you save it so you can check with picture files and whatnot, which setting you like best.

But alas, no color-saturation yet. ^ _ ^

If I find anything more I'll post here or if anyone would post their findings that'd be most beneficial. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the responsible edit, @Zanna

Comment: Still nothing, saturation-wise with Intel.

I, myself, have reverted to using Manjaro (no disrespect to Linux!) since it at least has a display scaling option built in to it now to make that ridiculous 1360x768 resolution a bit more production-friendly (for me at least). Yet, nothing there either, saturation adjustment-wise on these Intel cards. I suppose that's my final update in all this until there's one of those big announcements "Intel Opens Up to Linux" on OMG! Ubuntu and such ..

Try color profiles is my best suggestion; https://www.tftcentral.co.uk/articles/icc_profiles.htm